# Language Injection for constraint messages from ValidationMessages.properties

Tags: intellij-idea, bean-validation

I have my validation messages defined in the ValidationMessages.properties. The messages are referenced via the 'message' in the constraint annotation. I would like for Intellij's language injections to show me the value from the property file in place of the reference (similar to what it does with properties and the Spring EL).

Register.java:

```
...
@Size(min = 4, message = "{register.username.size}")
private String username;
...
```

ValidationMessages.properties:

```
register.username.size="Username must be at least {min} properties"
```

Desired outcome:

```
...
@Size(min = 4, message = "{Username must be at least {min} properties}")
private String username;
...
```

Is this possible and if so how can I achieve it?